# What is the purpose of having two folders in Azure Data-lake Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I am a newbie to Azure Data lake.

The below screenshot has 2 folders (Storage Account and Catalog), one for Datalake analytics and other data lake store.

My Question is why is the purpose of each folder and why are we using U-SQL for transformations when this can be done in the data factory.

Please explain the data flow process from the data store to the data lake.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDzr0.png)

Thanks you,
Addy

Answer (score 0):

I have addressed your query on MSDN thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8405bdb-0c85-4d37-8f2e-0dab983c7f94/what-is-the-purpose-of-having-two-folders-in-azure-datalake-analytics?forum=AzureDataLake

Hope this helps.